# HiveServer2 memory usage

Tags: java, memory, hive, heap-memory

I'm developing with HiveServer2, and investigating its environment.

It is said that HiveServer2 consumes a lot of memory. For instance, Cloudera says we need several gigabytes to run HiveServer2 server and MetaStore server:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_hiveserver2_configure.html

However, while I executed queries to see cpu and memory usage of servers, they seemed not to consume such much memory. Does anyone know if we really need much memory to run HiveServer2? Any suggestion and experience would be appreciated.

My environment:

- HiveServer2 with local metastore mode(version is cdh4.7, I think its hive version is equivalent to 0.10 with patch 0.11). Its heap size is 384MB.
- Java application as HiveServer2 client(submit queries):

  - Execution of 20 queries concurrently. The query is just to scan, but to generate several ten megabytes, like `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100000`
  - Execution of 20 queries concurrently. The query is to count: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`

[EDIT]

I've heard from several that the number of partitions may affect. I'll try it and see the result.

Comment: It's possible when there's many partitions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It means that a query which needs many partitions can use much memory?